# ASP.NET Task Async WaitingForActivation

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to send a post request to a third party API and retrieve the UserToken. Here is the code that does that:

```
        [HttpPost]
        private async Task<string> GetUserToken()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"grant_type", "client_credentials" },
                    {"client_id", _clientId },
                    {"client_secret", _clientSecret }
                };
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);

                var response = await client.PostAsync(_baseUrl, content);
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(responseString);
                UserTokenModel userToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserTokenModel>(responseString);
                Console.WriteLine(userToken.access_token);
                return userToken.access_token;
            }
        }
```

When I test this in a console application, it prints out the correct UserToken value. However, when I do a method call to this method and step through it in the debugger, the value of the Usertoken is set

`var userToken = GetUserToken();`
`Status: WaitingForActivation`
`Method:"{null}"`
`Result:"{Not yet Computed}"`

I'm not really sure why this is happening, but as a result, the value when used in other methods isn't set to the proper value. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetUserToken()` does not return a user token. It returns a `Task` which represents asynchronous work whose *result* is the user token.

In essence, the following code:

```
var userToken = GetUserToken();
```

... is rather meaningless.

What you really want is:

```
var userToken = await GetUserToken();
// Do something with the token.
```